# Tomcat trial Thawte certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https

I purchased a trial Thawte certificate. They gave me 3 certs:

1. root certificate
2. intemediate certificate
3. trial certificate

I did the follows:

1. Created keystore and local key pair (keytool -genkey -alias vskladchinu -keyalg RSA -keystore /usr/keystore)
2. Created csr (keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias vskladchinu -file certreq.csr -keystore /usr/keystore)
3. I got 3 certificates from thawte (based on generated csr)
4. I installed root and intermediate certs (keytool -import -alias root -keystore /usr/keystore -trustcacerts -file root.crt; keytool -import -alias intermediate -keystore /usr/keystore -trustcacerts -file intermediate.crt)
5. I installed my trial thawte cert (keytool -import -alias vskladchinu -keystore /usr/keystore -file cert.crt)

i setup web.xml of tomcatr 7 server. And run the application. But browser said - there are only 2 certs in the certificate chain root and trial, but root can not be trusted (i guess without intermediate).

How do i make intermediate sertificate work?

Comment: Didn't you try anything, e.g. googling for `java keystore install certificate`?

Comment: I sure did. Just updated my question, made it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part you will always get an error associated with trust with a Thawte Trail certificate. This is because that trail root certificate is not by default installed on the browser. It how Thawte controls free certificates.

The actual certificates SSL123, WebServer, etc… are actual production certificates where the root is installed on the browser and you shouldn’t get an error pertaining to not trusting the certificate with those ones.

The fact that you can connect and see the certificate that was issued to you means that SSL is working. But that error about trust will always happen with the trail certs.